# Python pandas plot font size

Tags: python, pandas

How to change font size in upper right corner in this example, sorry I don't know it's English name:
[Example](https://www.w3schools.com/python/pandas/pandas_plotting.asp)

Can I use pandas plot with matplotlib.pyplot? If I call plt.figure then it open own window.

Comment: That would be the legend.  I'm sorry, I don't know how to change the font size.

Comment: as @duffymo mentionded it is called `legend`s. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72755454/how-to-change-the-legend-font-size-of-pd-dataframe-plot-when-secondary-y-is

Answer (score 1):

Use `fontsize` in `plt.legend` method:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

x = [1,2,3,4,5]
y = [-1,-2,-3,-4,-5]

df = pd.DataFrame(x,y)
df.plot()
plt.legend(['Data'],fontsize=15)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, it works, but in my case there is two lines and only one legend. How to get two legends?

Comment: put all labels in the list `plt.legend(['Data_1', 'Data_2'],fontsize=15)`

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a dataframe named df with n columns and you want to plot its columns. You can insert the line:

```
plt.legend(df.columns.to_list(),fontsize=20)
```

The parameter `fontsize` modifies the size of the legend. As you see, the printed in legend is the name of the columns of the dataframe.